# formating numbers into Time format

Tags: excel, formula

I want to convert numbers (that represent seconds) into HH:MM:SS format (like shown in pic..) but don't want to split them.. I want to format it using some formula or

[image: formating method]

Comment: How would you like 715 seconds represented? That's 11 minutes and 15 seconds. What format do you want to represent it?

Comment: that 715 number is calculated with a formula from "data".. so what I want is to convert that number into Time format automatically.. like 00:11:15

Comment: So, you don't want to convert 715 to 00:11:15 but you want the data from which 715 was derived to be directly converted to 00:11:15. Is that right? If that is right, what does that original data look like?

Comment: I'll explain the whole picture..
I have a "DATA Sheet" from which I've extracting this number (715) using "sumif" function...
So what I want to do is to convert this "715" number into 00:11:15 format

Comment: I don't want to split it into /60/60/24 because I'm calculating something else using it and than it gives me wrong %

Comment: Excel stores times as fractions of a day. In the long run, it might be better to adapt to that reality than trying to format `715` to **look like** `00:11:15`.  You'll need a formula and a new column to do that. You will not be able to do that just with formatting.  And you won't be able to use the new column in your downstream calculations.  So probably the best solution is to change those calculations.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to display the 715 seconds as hours:minutes:seconds, you will need a helper column that you use just for display.

You can create it either as in your example screenshot, or using a formula:

```
=TEXT(B2/86400,"[hh]:mm:ss")
```

Note the brackets around `hh`.  That keeps the hours from rolling over every 24 and displays total hours correctly for instances where seconds > 86,400.

There's no way I know of to have 715 displayed as the associated hours:minutes:seconds in the same cell.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a formula like this to convert 715 to HH:MM:SS:

```
=TEXT(FLOOR((A1-FLOOR(A1/86400,1)*86400)/3600, 1), "00:") & text(floor((A1 - floor(A1/3600,1)*3600)/60, 1),"00:") & text(A1 - floor(A1/3600,1)*3600 - floor((A1 - floor(A1/3600,1)*3600)/60, 1)*60,"00")
```

Let's break it down.

**Get hours**

- A1 is seconds
- There are 86400 seconds in a day
- FLOOR(A1/86400, 1) gives us the floor of days
- Multiply that by 86400 will give us seconds in those days `FLOOR(A1/86400,1)*86400`
- Remove those many seconds from A1 and you get seconds remaining in the fraction of the last day `A1- FLOOR(A1/86400,1)*86400`
- Divide those remaining seconds with 3600 to get hours `FLOOR((A1- FLOOR(A1/86400,1)*86400 )/3600, 1)`
- Use TEXT function to format it to 2 digits and a colon at the end `TEXT(FLOOR((A1- FLOOR(A1/86400,1)*86400 )/3600, 1), "00:")`

Then, find remaining minutes and format it.

Then, take remaining seconds and format it.

## Alternate method

- Assume that your seconds are in column A6.
- In B6, we will put Whole Days `=FLOOR(A6/86400, 1)`
- In C6, we will put remaining seconds `=A6-B6*86400`
- In D6, we will put Whole Hours `=FLOOR(C6/3600,1)`
- In E6, we will put remaining seconds `=C6-D6*3600`
- In F6, we will put Whole Minutes `=FLOOR(E6/60, 1)`
- In G6, we will put remaining seconds `=E6-F6*60`
- In H6, we'll format Hours, Minutes and Seconds `=TEXT(D6,"00:") & TEXT(F6,"00:") & TEXT(G6,"00")`